# numbering words in thesaurus index file

Tags: hunspell, thesaurus

I will like to know how the thesaurus dictionaries are built. What is the relation between .dat file and index file .idx? For e.g. the relevant entry from th_en_CA_v2.dat file looks like this...

```
ploy|2
(noun)|gambit|remark (generic term)|comment (generic term)
(noun)|gambit|stratagem|maneuver (generic term)|manoeuvre (generic term)|tactical maneuver (generic term)|tactical manoeuvre (generic term)
```

The relevant entry from th_en_CA_v2.idx file

```
ploy|12626348
```

What is that number (12626348) next to word ploy?

Comment: Well, for a moment I wondered also what was the `2` at the first line of the dat file. Then observing the rest of the file it was clear that's the number of lines below it before the next entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the byte offset of the entry for `ploy` in the `.dat` file.