# Why sed's dot doesn't match ù in latin1 encoding?

Tags: regex, sed, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have two files containing the text `aùb`, but one, `critic_utf8` is encoded in UTF-8 and the other, `critic_latin1`, in latin1, so their content is like this

```
$ od -a critic_utf8 
0000000   a   C   9   b  nl
0000005
$ od -a critic_latin1 
0000000   a   y   b  nl
0000004
```

Now, leaving aside that I don't know what that `y` (which corresponds to `ù`) in the second output is (and I'd like to understand, so a subquestion is: what is that `y`?), it seems to me that Sed's `.` doesn't match it:

```
$ sed 's/.*/x/' critic_latin1 
xùb
$ sed 's/.*/x/' critic_utf8 
x
$ sed 's/./x/g' critic_latin1 
xùx
$ sed 's/./x/g' critic_utf8 
xxx
```

What does this mean? That Sed cannot work with latin1-encoded text files? Still, I thought `.` would match everything but newline, but here it is also not matching something else. And I know that `ù` is not reacting to `.` as `\n` would do, as proved by this:

```
$ sed -z 's/.*/x/' critic_latin1 
xùb
```

---

I've noticed this while playing around with `*.idx` and `*.dat` files (those with words and synonyms), when trying to experiment what I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31350984/5825294).

Comment: Most probably because it takes 2 bytes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, but why doesn't `.` consume all those bytes? I think I just don't understand what `.` matches in the two cases, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

1. `sed` command reads your file with `LANG` variable content formatted with *language*_*COUNTRY*.*CHARSET*
2. The `sed` command output is interpreted by your terminal following its own configuration

I reproduce your output with a `LANG` variable configured with `UTF-8` charset and a terminal configured with ISO-8859-1 (latin1) encoding :

```bash
> export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8; echo "latin1"; sed 's/.*/x/' critic_latin1 ; echo "utf-8"; sed 's/.*/x/' critic_utf8; echo "latin1/g"; sed 's/./x/g' critic_latin1; echo "utf-8/g"; sed 's/./x/g' critic_utf8
latin1
xùb
utf-8
x
latin1/g
xùx
utf-8/g
xxx
```

A `LANG` value with UTF-8 said to `sed` to work with UTF-8 characters but in your `critic_latin1` you have a `ù` character encoded in ISO-8859-1 (only one byte). This character is not valid in UTF-8. So `sed` does not treat unknown (invalid) characters.

If you want to work with files encoded differently than your `LANG` variable, prefix you works with `LANG=...` like this:

```bash
> export LANG=fr_FR.ISO-8859-1; echo "latin1"; sed 's/.*/x/' critic_latin1 ; echo "utf-8"; sed 's/.*/x/' critic_utf8; echo "latin1/g"; sed 's/./x/g' critic_latin1; echo "utf-8/g"; sed 's/./x/g' critic_utf8
latin1
x
utf-8
x
latin1/g
xxx
utf-8/g
xxxx
```

It's really useful with data text files (like ISAM).

Comment: By "_do not trait_" do you mean "_does not treat_"?